# Deleting/Copying the data from Database with specific condition in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for an Idea to handle data in DB directly.

**Here is my use case**

I have table “`EVENT_REGISTERED`” with column `(ID, Event_name,Event_DateTime)`

I want to display the `EVENT_REGISTERED` in the fronted end whose date and time is not passed. i.e. I want to display only Upcoming event not Historical events.

Of course this can be handle with `JS code` before displaying.

But What I want is there should be some sort of a trigger which will delete the Instance form the “`EVENT_ REGISTERED`” table and copy it to another Table “`HISTORICAL_EVENT`”
I cannot Create an MY SQL EVENT to do this as it like batch job and I cannot run this every 5 mins as there can be more than 10000 rows in there.

I see Trigger option as well, I am not sure how to use this as it says that it will be activated after the specific action is executed. Here the specific action is `CURRENT_DATETIME  == EVENT_DATETIME`.

**Can anybody give me a direction or any sort of alternative way to achieve this?**

**I am not an Expert of MySQL*
Thank you
Regards
Prat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't start moving rows between tables.  Simply run a query:

```
select er.*
from event_registered
where er.event_datetime > now();
```

With an index on `(event_datetime)`, performance should be fine.

Comment: @Gordan : eveyday there will be 3000 instance created in the table. So over a year dont you think it will performance issue.

Comment: @GameBuilder . . . A million rows per year?  No, I don't think that's a performance issue with the index.